# converting scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix to a list of lists

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am learning multi label classification and trying to implement the tfidf tutorial from scikit learning.
I am dealing with a text corpus to calculate its tf-idf score.
I am using the module sklearn.feature_extraction.text for the purpose.Using CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer I have now my corpus vectorised and tfidf for each vocabulary.
The problem is that I am having a sparse matrix now, like:

```
(0, 47) 0.104275891915
(0, 383)    0.084129133023
.
.
.
.
(4, 308)    0.0285015996586
(4, 199)    0.0285015996586
```

I want to convert this sparse.csr.csr_matrix into a list of lists so that I can get rid of the document id from the above csr_matrix and get the tfidf and vocabularyId pair like

```
47:0.104275891915 383:0.084129133023
.
.
.
.
308:0.0285015996586 
199:0.0285015996586
```

Is there any  way to convert into a list of lists or any other way with which i can change the format to get tfidf-vocabularyId pair ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know what `tf-idf` expects, but I may be able help with the sparse end.

Make a sparse matrix:

```
In [526]: M=sparse.random(4,10,.1)
In [527]: M
Out[527]: 
<4x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [528]: print(M)
  (3, 1)    0.281301619779
  (2, 6)    0.830780358032
  (1, 1)    0.242503399296
  (2, 2)    0.190933579917
```

Now convert it to `coo` format.  This is already that (I could have given the `random` a format parameter).  In any case the values in `coo` format are stored in 3 arrays:

```
In [529]: Mc=M.tocoo()
In [530]: Mc.data
Out[530]: array([ 0.28130162,  0.83078036,  0.2425034 ,  0.19093358])
In [532]: Mc.row
Out[532]: array([3, 2, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [533]: Mc.col
Out[533]: array([1, 6, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Looks like you want to ignore `Mc.row`, and somehow join the others.

For example as a dictionary:

```
In [534]: {k:v for k,v in zip(Mc.col, Mc.data)}
Out[534]: {1: 0.24250339929583264, 2: 0.19093357991697379, 6: 0.83078035803205375}
```

or a columns in a 2d array:

```
In [535]: np.column_stack((Mc.col, Mc.data))
Out[535]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.28130162],
       [ 6.        ,  0.83078036],
       [ 1.        ,  0.2425034 ],
       [ 2.        ,  0.19093358]])
```

(Also `np.array((Mc.col, Mc.data)).T`)

Or as just a list of arrays `[Mc.col, Mc.data]`, or `[Mc.col.tolist(), Mc.data.tolist()]` list of lists, etc.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you.
Its exactly what I needed.

Comment: I want to highlight the dict comprehension `{k:v for k,v in zip(Mc.col, Mc.data)}`. It's a fantastic way of keeping the data sparse, while also having human-readable labels.

Comment: This is good. But all the zeros dissapear from the tfidf Matrix..So they will all have different dimensions now

Comment: 'col' no longer is valid. Now it is 'indices'

Comment: @DavidNogueira.  The attributes of a `coo` fromat include `col`.  In the `csr` format these are replaced by `indices`.  Each format stores its data in a unique set of attributes.

Comment: @hpaulj is `{k:v for k,v in zip(Mc.col, Mc.data)}` gives matrix sum? I mean, if you have `(4, 308) : 0.2` and `(4,309) : 0.3` is output will look like this `4: 0.5`?

Comment: @VladFedo, no it doesn't sum - see my example.

Comment: @hpaulj oh, okay, thank you, Is it possible to print matrix sum with row names using your example?

Comment: @VladFedo, I can imagine accumulating such a sum with a `defaultdict`.  The `csr` `sum` method uses matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Base on [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.tolil.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.tolil) I suggest to use this method:

```
ndarray = yourMatrix.toarray()
listOflist = ndarray.tolist()
```

Comment: update: youtMatrix.tolil(copy=False)

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, proper use of the scipy sparse matrix types is essential [scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). In this case scipy.sparse.lil_matrix it's ideal, whose "data" attribute stores an np.array of lists that represent the column values.
A brief script follows

```
arrays_of_list = matriz.tolil().data
list_of_list = arrays_of_list.tolist()
```

Comment: don't use code snippets if the snippet is not executable, just use code formatting (ctrl+k).