# TFIDF vectorizer: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I've been trying to apply TFIDF vectorizer on a gensim LDA model with no success. It looks like I have to use any() or all() but I'm not sure what is going on with the vectorizer. The data has been cleaned and pre-processed.

Data:

```
text_data=
0         [new, leaked, treasury, document, full, sugges...
1         [tommy, robinson, endorsing, boris, johnson's,...
2         [thanks, already, watched, corbyn, catch, tv, ...
3         [treasury, document, check, boris, johnson, to...
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# Create dummy function to initialize

def dummy_fun(doc):
    return doc

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(
    analyzer='word',
    tokenizer=dummy_fun,
    preprocessor=dummy_fun,
    token_pattern=None)  

# Fit and transform on text_data
tfidf_corpus = tfidf.fit_transform(text_data)

# Use LDA model to find 10 topics in the data, based on TFIDF vectorizer

ldamodel_tfidf = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=tfidf_corpus,
                                       #id2word=id2word,
                                       num_topics=10, 
                                       random_state=42,
                                       update_every=1,
                                       chunksize=100,
                                       passes=10,
                                       alpha='auto',
                                       per_word_topics=True)
```

The error is asking that I use any() or all(), but why is it asking for this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-25-57489833d281> in <module>
          9                                            passes=10,
         10                                            alpha='auto',
    ---> 11                                            per_word_topics=True)

    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py in __init__(self, corpus, num_topics, id2word, distributed, chunksize, passes, update_every, alpha, eta, decay, offset, eval_every, iterations, gamma_threshold, minimum_probability, random_state, ns_conf, minimum_phi_value, per_word_topics, callbacks, dtype)
        431         if self.id2word is None:
        432             logger.warning("no word id mapping provided; initializing from corpus, assuming identity")
    --> 433             self.id2word = utils.dict_from_corpus(corpus)
        434             self.num_terms = len(self.id2word)
        435         elif len(self.id2word) > 0:

    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py in dict_from_corpus(corpus)
        824 
        825     """
    --> 826     num_terms = 1 + get_max_id(corpus)
        827     id2word = FakeDict(num_terms)
        828     return id2word

    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py in get_max_id(corpus)
        733     maxid = -1
        734     for document in corpus:
    --> 735         if document:
        736             maxid = max(maxid, max(fieldid for fieldid, _ in document))
        737     return maxid

    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __bool__(self)
        285             return self.nnz != 0
        286         else:
    --> 287             raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
        288                              "element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().")
        289     __nonzero__ = __bool__

    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Just added the error

Comment: Have you done any research? This is quite a common error.

Comment: It is common but also I've found the questions/answers to be highly contextualised. Do you have any light to shed on this?

Comment: @PhilipLiu Can you link to some of the resources you’ve found to be too contextualized? If many are indeed lacking, it might be worth it to produce a solid answer here. Do you understand the idea behind the error, even if you can’t currently pinpoint the exact cause?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=tfidf_corpus)` takes corpus as iterable int,float pair and the input you are giving(tfidi_corpus) is a sparce matrix.

try this [converting scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix to a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694972/converting-scipy-sparse-csr-csr-matrix-to-a-list-of-lists)